# angularjs ng-table next page send ajax

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

i get the date form server side and show in ng-table,but i don't dnow how to send a ajax request to server side when i click the next page button

```js
var query = sysAuthorityService.getData('code', 'name');
var data = [];
query.get(function(myData) {
  data = myData.data.list;
  $scope.tableEdit = new ngTableParams({
    page: 1,            // show first page
    count: 10           // count per page
  }, {
    total: myData.data.total, // length of data
    getData: function($defer, params) {
      $defer.resolve(data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
    }
  });
});
```

And i have a confuse too..
it's my first use AngularJS,when i want to pagination,we need to load all data from server side,and pagination by ng-table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should rewrite the getData function. For example, the following is some code in my project:

```
{
total: 0
getData: function($defer, params){
            var filter = params.filter();
            var sorting = params.sorting();
            var count = params.count();
            var page = params.page();
            taskService.get_task_instance(page, count, filter, sorting, $stateParams.id).then(function(data){
                var total = parseInt(data['total']);
                params.total(total);
                $defer.resolve(data['msg']);
            });
        }
}
```